# Add XML content to a View

Tags: android

im developing an application and I need to add elements dynamically. I wonder if I can append elements (stored in a XML file) in my current Activity, like innerHTML in JavaScript.

I tried LayoutInflater but that replaces all the content and I need to append.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to inflate your xml into a view. Perhaps you should post some code since this is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Im looking for a "conceptual answer", I think my code won't help lol. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I noticed you used my answer in a different question, yet didn't update your question here nor gave me any credit. I didn't post on the other answer, but if you update this one I can tell you what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the LayoutInflater as you said. I'm not sure how you were doing it (hence why I asked to see your inflating code), but the simplest way to understand is to do the following:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View viewToAppend = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, null);
// Optional, create LayoutParams and apply to view with 
// viewToAppend.setLayoutParams(params);
mainView.addView(viewToAppend);
```

Comment: +1 since there was no code posted in the question: This is the best possible answer ;-)